# Are my Bell Pepper seeds showing signs of germination?

Tags: bell-peppers

I’m new to growing bell pepper plant. Surfed through the web and found the paper towel and ziplock method and I thought of adopting that. It has been at least 3-4 days now and I want to know if the seeds or rotting or showing a sign that it is going to germinate soon.
By the way, the temperature here is 25-26 degree Celsius.
Also give me some tips on growing the plant further.
Thanks
[image: seed1][image: Seed2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v02uI.jpg![Seed3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pepper seeds are covered by a thick seed shell and oil as they are supposed to pass through the gut of a bird for dispersal. Seed viability is low at about 50% even for seeds under two years of age.   Germination inside a Ziploc bag can take three weeks but as low as eight days at a temperature of 30°C.  Your seeds have not germinated yet nor are they showing signs of rot.

Comment: Thanks man, but my doubt is what are those green stuff in the seeds?

Comment: Also, how do i maintain the 30°C without a heater?

Comment: Seed coat absorbing water? Can't really tell without high magnification. Hot water cupboard?

Comment: yeah looks like the seeds have absorbed some water, as its a little bigger due to osmosis i guess......

Answer (score 1):

At least 1 of the seeds in the picture has germinated, I suspect maybe a couple of more.  (There is 1 seed where there is a "tail" clearly visible in the coating)